# Spring Boot 3 upgrade causing EntityNotFoundException with @Filter on Hibernate 5

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-6.x

I have a Spring Boot 2 project where I use @Filter to apply extra where conditions on queries. I have three scopes: A, B, and C, each with its own set of users and managers. Managers from each scope cannot view the users from other scopes. However, some entities, like Campaign, are common and should be viewable by all managers scopes. Campaign has a relation to all scope users.

In Spring Boot 2, everything works fine. However, after upgrading to Spring Boot 3, common APIs started throwing the following exception, and managers cannot view scope campaigns:

`jakarta.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find User with id 11`

Here are the relevant code snippets:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Filter(name = "ScopeFilter")
data class User(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Int = 0,

    var scope: Scope = Scope.A
)


@Entity
@Table(name = "campaigns")
data class Campaign(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Int = 0,

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    var user: User = User()
)
```

I suspect that in Hibernate 5, @Filter("ScopeFilter") is not applied to entity relational fields, but in Hibernate 6.2, it is.
Can someone confirm this, and suggest a solution or workaround to make this work on Spring Boot 3 and Hibernate 6?

Comment: Have you read the Hibernate 6 upgrade documentation? If there was a big change regarding that I'm sure it will be mentioned in there.